# Error while installing npm

Tags: node.js, npm

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed

```
   Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-ansi but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-nopt (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
```

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I have tried **sudo apt-get install -f** but still got the same error.
Please help

Comment: sudo apt-get install npm

Answer (score 0):

You get npm when you install nodejs. So try the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Source: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions.

Note that you cannot install npm without node, as npm relies heavily on it. See this [thread](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12230) on github for details.

Comment: I have already installed nodejs. After that I tried to install npm and got the error.

Comment: Most likely, you already have npm installed. Try doing `npm -v` in your terminal and tell me what you get?

Comment: npm -v give result 3.8.6

Comment: ok. Thanks. Actually I am struggling with the installation of appium and follow steps. These steps tell me install npm. Do you have any idea on how to install appium. I have tried npm install -g appium but get error :- Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2

Comment: I think you should make a separate question for that and show the full error in there.